# How do I set eclipse to compile as a .dll and actually execute when run?

Tags: c++, eclipse, dll

I've told eclipse to compile as a shared library, yet it automatically made it a .so. I changed the compile extension to .dll in settings and then tried to compile again. I then injected it into my test process, yet the entry point didn't run. I figure i've done something wrong, so I ask you - What's the correct way to create .dll's in eclipse.

My test code:

```
#include <windows.h>

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE module_handle, DWORD reason_for_call, LPVOID reserved)
{

    if(reason_for_call == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        MessageBox(0,0,0,0);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

EDIT: DLL is being run via LoadLibrary

Comment: Why are you using a Java IDE for c++?

Comment: Because I don't want to use Visual Studio, and It has a nice integration of GCC :), Also it's not just for java.

Comment: Visual Studio will build a DLL for you really easily though? Seems as though you're making it harder for yourself by using eclipse, which isn't designed for C++

Comment: I don't want to use the visual studio compiler.

Comment: @ZachRoss-Clyne Eclipse is a multi-language IDE, I used it with C/C++ and compiled both .exe and .dll. However, I used MinGW toolset and I never needed to rename files.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that your DLL cannot find any of its dependencies (C runtime library for example) and thus it cannot be loaded. Analyze the imports in your DLL.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov - http://www.snorflake.com/u/CcQM.png It's all there, yet when I inject into my test process the message box does not pop up.

Comment: I've found the cause! On VS It exports something different! Do you know how to change what the entry point is exported as? http://www.snorflake.com/u/lYir.png

Comment: You do not need to change the exported entry point otherwise C/C++ runtime won't be initialized correctly. If you don't use any of the standard C functions, you can try to change it. If you don't use static linking of C runtime library when creating DLL, then the required runtime must be available on the `PATH`.

Comment: I'd suggest checking the return value of `LoadLibrary`. Is your DLL really loaded?

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov Yes it is. I even pasted the code into visual studio and compiled as .dll, that worked fine.

Comment: Obviously, it should work with gcc too. I see no reason why it shouldn't. Yet there are *too many* variables to give the solution. *Also note:* that Visual Studio usually registers its runtime DLL globally; GCC may not do it. If your app with DLL compiled in VS works fine in a freshly installed Windows, then you can be sure there are no additional external dependencies. If it doesn't, you have to have C/C++ runtime DLL available.

Comment: By the way, showing MessageBox from `DllMain` is not a good idea. So I'd recommend removing `MessageBox` call from your `DllMain`. You should add another function to your DLL and call it to check whether DLL is loaded. If `LoadLibrary` returns non-NULL, the library loaded *successfully*; otherwise DLL isn't loaded. If you really want to make sure `DllMain` is executed, use debugger.